# The group $\mathrm{GL}_n$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

I know that with entries over a field, $\mathrm{GL}_n (F)$, the set of $n \times n$ matrices with entries in $F$, is a group under multiplication.

Do the entries need to come from a field, however?

I've seen this defined with entries from a ring or commutative ring. It doesn't seem to me that a commutative ring is necessary since matrix multiplication doesn't commute, but I do, importantly, require that the ring contain an identity element. Otherwise, the identity matrix won't be contained in $\mathrm{GL}_n (R)$.

Comment: For a commutative ring $R$ with unit the group $GL_n(R)$ is indeed considered frequently. The most basic case is of course the arithmetic group $GL_n(\Bbb Z)$.

Comment: Fact is that it's partially a matter of definitions (though the characterizations are interesting). $GL(n,R)$ over a non-commutative ring $R$ may be taken to be the group of (two-sided) units of the algebra $M(n,R)$. This definition specializes to all cases, but in the commutative case (where determinants make sense) you also have that it's equal to the group of matrices with determinant in $R^*$. This specializes to fields as the group of matrices with non-zero determinant. But none of the specializations work backwards (i.e. they do not identify a multiplicative *group*).

Comment: You do not need commutativity either. In fact, some of the theory of vector spaces may be done completely analogously over skew fields, i.e. non-commutative fields, rather than fields.

Comment: And you need that the matrix is invertible over the ring (and not only over a larger field), e.g. because the determinant is a unit in the ring.